# ¿Como extraer datos de una tabla con scraping en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scrapy

Pienso tomar un ***mooc*** de scraping con ***Ruby on Rails***, para sacar el máximo provecho al curso estoy leyendo unos tutoriales como hacer scraping y adelantándome a las posibles tareas.

Creé en github una página web que simula los datos que quiero extraer:

https://rrg1459.github.io/extraerDatos/

Y tengo el siguiente helper llamado `clientes_helper.rb` que me extrae los datos correctamente:

```
module ClientesHelper

    def consulta_cliente
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'nokogiri'
        url = "https://rrg1459.github.io/extraerDatos/"
        begin
            @hayInternet = true
            doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))

            inline_script = doc.search('//tr')
            inline_script.each do |script|
                linea = script.text.strip

                linea = linea.gsub("\t","")
                linea = linea.gsub("\n","")
                linea = linea.gsub("</table>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("<tr>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("<td>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("</td>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("<b>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("</b>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("</tr>","")
                linea = linea.gsub("<td align=\"left\">","")
                linea = linea.gsub("  ","")
                linea = linea.gsub("<font color=\"#00387b\">","")

                if /ID/ =~ linea 
                    @id_cliente = linea.split(':')[1]
                elsif /Nombre/ =~ linea
                    @cliente_nombre = linea.split(':')[1]
                elsif /stado/ =~ linea
                    @cliente_estado = linea.split(':')[1]
                elsif /REGULAR/ =~ linea
                    @cliente_regular = linea.split(':')[1]
                elsif /Dirección/ =~ linea
                    @direccion_cliente = linea.split(':')[1]
                end
            end
        rescue
            @hayInternet = false
        end

    end
end
```

Pero se ve horrible y no es la mejor técnica, creo que puede ser ofensivo a algunos ojos experimentados y de antemano pido disculpas.

Estoy bastante consciente del principio de Ruby on Rails de ***”convención sobre configuración”*** y trato de ser fiel a este principio y no logro hacer que se vea limpio, parco, preciso.

Y la verdad, estoy más enredado que perro comiendo chicle.

Alguien me puede guiar sobre como es la mejor práctica para extraer estos datos de una forma elegante tipo Ruby.

De antemano agradecido por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la más importante mejora que puedes hacer en tu código es usar nokogiri correctamente.
Al buscar `//tr` estás retornando e iterando por 14 etiquetas que encontró en tu HTML, lo cual es ineficiente, ya que iteras por más etiquetas de las que deberías y aparte tienes que remover todos esos saltos de línea y tags html (que de por cierto, no son necesarios, ya que `.text` los remueve).

Mejor sería que accedas directamente a los 4 tr que necesitas a través de su [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41686271/895789):

```
inline_script = doc.search('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr')
inline_script[0].search('td[2]').text # "D-123456789"
inline_script[1].search('td[2]').text # "PEDRITO DE LOS PALOTES"
inline_script[2].search('td[2]').text # "SI"
inline_script[3].search('td[2]').text # "CALLE CARCA DE ALGO, AL LADO DE UNA ESQUINA"
```

Comment: Amigo, funciona muy bien en el enlace que te pasé, el enlace de github, pero cuando le paso la dirección real, que es un http (es una dirección no segura, no es un https) no camina, me copié la página real a mi estación de trabajo y la accedo localmente también funciona, creo que el problema es con el acceso http. 

Nota adicional:

después de hacer esto doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))

hago un doc.inspect me trae todo el esquema de la página.

Comment: No sabría ayudarte con la información que entregas, creo que podrías realizar otra pregunta con tu problema específico de conexión (además de incluir más información), ya que al parecer escapa del contexto de ésta. Saludos

Comment: No quise ser grosero, ni irrespetuoso, si esa fue la impresión que dí te pido disculpas, igual y como siempre la información que me pasaste ha sido de calidad y oportuna, me ha servido para entrar en el camino correcto, debe ser algún detalle que falta, ya creo estar cerca de encontrarlo.

Comment: @rrg1459 jajajaja, no me malentiendas, no era mi intención llamarte la atención o algo similar. Solo pensaba que si inicias otra pregunta, podrías llamar más la atención de otr@s progamadoræs que quisieran contestar, pero sin ninguna animosidad de por medio. Saludos